# return from an update text field asynchronously - iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa, asynchronous, timer

I'm wondering the best approach to take for this.

The example app is:- I have a text field and button.  click the button, initiates a task to update the text field.  But the text field needs to be updated on a timer (or in background), say every 1 sec, but I only need the timer to run for say 5 secs, populating a random piece of text for example.

This should give the impression that the text box is displaying random words every sec, then  after the 5 secs has completed, the timer can stop and the last value remains in the text box.

But I also want to detect the stop event and then pick up the value in the text field and perform another action.

Finally the question :-

Should I use Timer events, or operations and queues ? Not sure which approach is best.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a timer in this way, `repeats:YES` is what you need:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self 
                     selector:@selector(ChangeText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void) ChangeText 
{
  _textfield.text = [nsstring stringwithformat:@"%@%@", _textfield.text, _yourstring];
}
```

Comment: many thanks, for some reason, I was over-thinking and over complicating the task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , above answer is correct, just need some small changes according to your question...

```
  count = 0;

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self 
                 selector:@selector(ChangeText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 - (void) ChangeText 
  {
    if (count < 5)
    {
      _textfield.text = [nsstring stringwithformat:@"%@%@", _textfield.text, _yourstring];
    }
    else
    {
      //Start your next event here;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

NSTimer able to work only on main thread, then you don't need to expect that it will fire if it launched in background. 
Also I think it's basically question of good architecture - don't you want try to handle events to update your textfield? For example, handle event when some task is finished or displayed value changed, then use delegate/block/NSNotification to receive event and update UI.